Root filesystem requires manual fsck, normal solutions not working
enter image description hereI have tried the normal solution,
Fsck -yf/dev/sdax,
And have typed y in multiple prompts. It resolved.
But, again the same error occurs while restarting and the above solution is not working.
Then, i used recovery mode and fixed fsck.
Then resumed to boot,after recovery, a black screen comes and stays. When rebooted again, the same error pops up
But, again, the same problem cannot be resolved

You've provided almost no specifics. We don't know what Ubuntu product & release you're using, what file-system is involved, nor if you actually performed the correct command (fsck is appropriate only for some file-systems) and it was performed whilst fs was not mounted (results may not be trustworthy if mounted).

Linux version is 2.37.2

2.37.2 is the fsck version, Ubuntu (server, Desktop, ...? please state) versions are yy.mm, like 22.04.  How are you shutting down the system? A rootfilesystem check needs to be done from another system (like the install media/try). A bad disk is possible, so from the smartmontools package run smartctl -a /dev/sda2  Add requested information to your original posting, comments may be removed in the future.

I don't know how to find the linx version. I remember version 22.04. what is root file system check needs to be done with another system mean?
